# Integrate Google Analytics with Static Firebase Hosting Website

Tags: google-analytics, firebase-hosting

i have made my website with wordpress and then used simply static plugin to generate static files which later on i host on firebase hosting. I want to add google analytics to my website so i have added analytics script in my website pages header using another wordpress plugin. The problem is that analytics does not get shown on google analytics site. Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"